# iphone blue dot AND pin at same time -

Tags: iphone, mapkit, core-location

please help, this question has been asked so many times before, but peoples suggestions have no effect on my outcome, all i want, is the pin and blue circle (Accuracy) to be shown on the map, here is my implementation. - oh, im using an iPhone device - im not in the simulator

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{


NSLog(@"View for Annotation is called");

if (NSClassFromString(@"MKUserLocation")==[annotation class]) {
    return nil;
}

if (annotation == mapView.userLocation) {
    return nil;
}



MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];

annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn;
annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;

annView.canShowCallout = YES;
annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
pinDropped = TRUE;
return annView;
```

}

cheers in advance.... bloody thing

Comment: Have you set mapView.showsUserLocation to YES?  The second `if` doesn't make sense since it just checks if an annotation is the same type as itself.

Comment: yes set everything that needs to be set regarding this, removed second if statement.. cheers

Comment: What is being displayed? Do you get the pin? Or do you get the blue dot and circle? Or neither? It's tough to debug without knowing what you're actually getting.

Comment: if i check if the annotation is kindOfClass MKUserLocation, i only get the blue circle, if i ignore the check and go straight into creating an MKPinAnnotationView object - i get the pin, sorry - should have made that clearer

Comment: Just to confirm: You see the "View for Annotation is called" message on the console, right?  Can you show the addAnnotation section of the code that adds the pin to the map?  The above code should work but you only need one of the if statements.

Comment: @Anna - got it - annAnnotation was not implemented how I had done previosuly, im assuming this was preventing the pin from showing. I have now sorted the problem. thanks though guys,  i did say i overlooked something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure implemented [mapview addAnnotation:*annotation*];

thanks Anna for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Simulator then you're likely encountering the not-well-known difference in the way that CoreLocation and MapKit figure your current position.

### In the Simulator

**CoreLocation** will *always* use Apple's headquarters in Cupertino, California, USA as your current location. This is where the blue dot will always appear on the map.

**MapKit** will always use something approximating your actual current location using Apple's database of IP address and WiFi hotspot information. This is where the map will center if you tell it to use your current location.

As a result, the map will center on your current location but the blue dot will be over in Cupertino.

### On an iOS Device

**CoreLocation** puts the blue dot on something approximating your actual current location.

**MapKit** centers the map on something approximating your actual current location.

As a result you'll see the blue dot in the center of the map when using an actual iOS device.

This bit of knowledge can save a lot of stress. :)

Comment: previously read this bit of information along time ago, maybe my question should state im using a iPhone device for location rather than simulator. i am well aware which api does what and what information this displays/provides - i have previosuly displayed both the pin and blue approximation circle. The question was, how to show both the pin and blue circle, not how mapkit / CL obtain my position but thanks for the information

Comment: @burrows111 It's an extremely common reason that people have this problem, so it was worth a shot. Please take a look at my clarification comment to your question, above.

Comment: Cheers Matthew :) - atleast we all sorted... it is indeed a common problem, i knew there was something i overlooked. Happy Coding... @Matthew Frederick

Answer (score 1):

just in case someone was wondering, this also works:

```
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
{
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in my code

```
if(annotation == mapView.userLocation){
            return nil;
 }
```

Try that and let us know

Comment: no luck with that one either :( - im clearly overlooking something.  i have shown your suggestion in my question. thanks though